# Notepad++ search functionanilty

Tags: search, replace, notepad++

I have a rather large document that I am trying to modify. I am trying to change

```
<entity class="Style" count="29">
<entity class="Style" count="40">
<entity class="Style" count="50">
```

to

```
<entity class="Style" count="1">
<entity class="Style" count="1">
<entity class="Style" count="1">
```

In the replace I tried doing

```
<entity class="Style" count="^\d">
```

but that doesn't seem to be working.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Use `<entity class="Style" count="\d+">` and replace with `<entity class="Style" count="1">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the start of line anchor `^` and add `+` after `\d` to match 1 or more digits:

*Find*: `<entity class="Style" count="\d+">`

*Replace with*: `<entity class="Style" count="1">`
*Regular expression*: `Enabled`

[image]